# Need to build a WPF application with good architecture

Tags: prism, mvvm-foundation

I am trying to start a WPF application towards self learning curve, i have explored quite about WPF and now its time for me to start an application for myself.

Many thanks to them who contributed excellent articles to public here in internet. I would like to start with MVVM + PRISM.

Can anyone guide me through this, which other articles can help me to furnish this kind of architecture. OR what would be the best architecture to choose among MVVM + Nhibernate, Prism, + IOC (spring.net, Unity, NInject)

Thanks in advance

Regards
krish

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to learn, Try out an client server application
In Server Side try using

- EF Code First,
- Repository Pattern
- Service Layers & WCF

*Try using Dependency Injection & Containers for them. 
Use T4 for generating WCF client Proxies*

Client Side use

- Prism Modules & Regions
- MVVM Pattern
- Create or Use a Navigation Framework
- Validation System
- Custom selectors and Dialogs

*Use Dependency Injection & Containers. Task Parallel Library for Service calls. Background Workers, Multiple Threads to deal with UI updations.*

Comment: Joseph, 
Sorry I overlooked responding to your post. Glad that I opened my stack inbox. 

Thank you for taking time n replying to this post. I was searching for good sample application reflecting above structure. If you have any please share with me. 

Thanks once again.